# Hyperlink control in gridview using label values

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink, label

Here is my gridview code for displaying a pivot table from main data source

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">

protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.Redirect("Elect_CrewAccid.aspx?strdt=" + txtstrdt.Text + "&enddt=" + txtenddt.Text + "&reportedto=" + txtrepdt.Text);

} 

 </script>
 <script runat="server">
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        lblstrdt.Text = Request.QueryString["strdt"];
        lblenddt.Text = Request.QueryString["enddt"];
        lblreprtd.Text = Request.QueryString["reportedto"];
        if (Request.QueryString["reportedto"] == "") lblreportedto.Text = "Railway & Railway Board";
        if (Request.QueryString["reportedto"] == "RLY") lblreportedto.Text = "Railway";
        if (Request.QueryString["reportedto"] == "RLBD") lblreportedto.Text = "Railway Board";

    }

}
 </script>
 <script runat="server">

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        switch ((e.Row.FindControl("Label2") as Label).Text)
        {
            case "SPAD":
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Pink;
                break;

        }
    }
}

</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    .style2
    {
        font-size: small;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .style3
    {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .style4
    {
        font-family: Tahoma;
    }
    .style6
    {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .style7
    {
        font-family: Tahoma;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .style8
    {
        font-size: small;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Tahoma;
    }
    .style9
    {
        font-family: Tahoma;
        font-size: small;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .style10
    {
        font-family: Tahoma;
        font-size: small;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div style="text-align: center; font-weight: 700; font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'; color: #0000CC">
    Accident (including SPAD incidences) attributed to Loco Pilots under Administrative
    Control of Electrical</div>
<table align="left" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: small">
    <tr>
        <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <b>From Date:</b><asp:TextBox ID="txtstrdt" runat="server" Contenteditable="false" /><span
                class="style2">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="DateRequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="txtstrdt"
                    ErrorMessage="Name" Text="Can not be left blank" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"
                    ForeColor="Red" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Small" />
                <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtstrdt"
                    Format="dd-MMM-yy">
                </ajax:CalendarExtender>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td style="margin-left: 80px">
            <span class="style3">Up to Date:</span><asp:TextBox ID="txtenddt" runat="server"
                Contenteditable="false" /><span class="style2">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtenddt"
                        ErrorMessage="Name" Text="Can not be left blank" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"
                        ForeColor="Red" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Small" /></span>
        </td>
        <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtenddt"
            Format="dd-MMM-yy">
        </ajax:CalendarExtender>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSend" Text="Submit" runat="server" onclick="btnSend_Click"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="txtrepdt" runat="server" Style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: small">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Reoprted To Rly & Board" Value="" Selected="true"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Reported to Rly" Value="RLY"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Reported to Rly Board" Value="RLBD"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<div>
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td class="style9" align="center">
                <span class="style10"><strong>Cases From Date: </strong></span><span class="style6">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblstrdt" runat="server" Style="color: #CC0000" CssClass="style10" /></span>
            </td>
            <td class="style11" align="center">
                <span class="style10"><strong>&nbsp;to: </strong></span>
                <asp:Label ID="lblenddt" runat="server" Style="color: #CC0000" CssClass="style9" />
            </td>
            <td class="style9" align="center">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td class="style9" align="center">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td class="style7" align="center">
                <span class="style10"><strong>Reprorted to: </strong></span>
                <asp:Label ID="lblreportedto" runat="server" Style="color: #CC0000;" CssClass="style9" />
            </td>
            <td class="style10" align="center">
                <strong>Category</strong>
            </td>
            <td class="style7" align="center">
                <span class="style4"></span>
                <asp:Label ID="lblreprtd" runat="server" Visible="false" Style="color: #CC0000;"
                    CssClass="style9" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ShowFooter="True" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"
    EmptyDataText="Oops.... nothing to diplay! Select another dates." HorizontalAlign="Center"
    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966"
    BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Classification" SortExpression="Classification" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"
            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"
            ItemStyle-Wrap="true">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Classification") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Classification") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                Total
            </FooterTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></HeaderStyle>
            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Tahoma" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="True"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CR" SortExpression="CR">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CR") %>'></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:HyperLink ID="LabeCR" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CR") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/detailspage.aspx?Rly=CR&Classification={0}", Eval("Classification")) %>'></asp:HyperLink>

            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridViewCR" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlign="Center"
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceCR" ShowHeader="False" RowStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"
                    RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" GridLines="None" SelectedRowStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"
                    SelectedRowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Total" HeaderText="Total" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Total"
                            ShowHeader="False" ItemStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-Font-Names="Tahoma" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                            ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceCR" runat="server" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EsafetyConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="safety_summary_TTL"
                    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="reportedto" QueryStringField="reportedto" Type="String" />
                        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="strdt" QueryStringField="strdt" Type="DateTime" />
                        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="enddt" QueryStringField="enddt" Type="DateTime" />
                        <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="CR" Name="Railway" QueryStringField="Railway"
                            Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ER" SortExpression="ER">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ER") %>'></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="LabeCR" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ER") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/detailspage.aspx?Rly=ER&Classification={0}", Eval("Classification")) %>'></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridViewER" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlign="Center"
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceER" ShowHeader="False" RowStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"
                    RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" GridLines="None" SelectedRowStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"
                    SelectedRowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Total" HeaderText="Total" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Total"
                            ShowHeader="False" ItemStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-Font-Names="Tahoma" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                            ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceER" runat="server" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EsafetyConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="safety_summary_TTL"
                    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="reportedto" QueryStringField="reportedto" Type="String" />
                        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="strdt" QueryStringField="strdt" Type="DateTime" />
                        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="enddt" QueryStringField="enddt" Type="DateTime" />
                        <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="ER" Name="Railway" QueryStringField="Railway"
                            Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total" SortExpression="Total">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LabelTotal" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Total") %>'></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LabelTotal" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Total") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridViewTotal" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlign="Center"
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceTotal" ShowHeader="False" RowStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"
                    RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" GridLines="None" SelectedRowStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"
                    SelectedRowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Total" HeaderText="Total" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Total"
                            ShowHeader="False" ItemStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-Font-Names="Tahoma" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                            ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceTotal" runat="server" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EsafetyConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="safety_summary_TTL"
                    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="reportedto" QueryStringField="reportedto" Type="String" />
                        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="strdt" QueryStringField="strdt" Type="DateTime" />
                        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="enddt" QueryStringField="enddt" Type="DateTime" />
                        <asp:QueryStringParameter  Name="Railway" QueryStringField="Railway"
                            Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center"
        VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Names="Tahoma" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"
        BackColor="White" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FEFCEB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#AF0101" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F6F0C0" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#7E0000" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EsafetyConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="safety_summary"
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="reportedto" QueryStringField="reportedto" Type="String" />
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="strdt" QueryStringField="strdt" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="enddt" QueryStringField="enddt" Type="DateTime" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
<p class="style8">
    <strong><a href="../../elocosmainpage.htm">Home</a></strong></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the difficulty is that how to add values of 'lblstrdt', 'lblenddt' & 'lblreprtd' to following hyperlink

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="LabeCR" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CR") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/detailspage.aspx?Rly=CR&Classification={0}", Eval("Classification")) %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

so that I can get the following query string to display corresponding record(s) on details page

```
 "~/detailspage.aspx?Rly=CR&Classification=xxxx&strdt=xx/xx/xx&enddt=xx/xx/xx&reprtd=xxxxx"
```

Or kindly suggested another method / code to obtain the desired results.  I am unable to find out solution even doing lot of googling. Link to my webpage where this hyperlink is required to be implemented is - http://elocos.railnet.gov.in/ElectSafety/Elect_CrewAccid.aspx. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="LabeCR" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CR") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/detailspage.aspx?Rly=CR&Classification={0}&{1}", Eval("Classification"), Request.QueryString.ToString()) %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```